# Unable to remove newline between spool output

Tags: sqlplus

I am not able to remove the newline between each record of generated spool file. I have the set commands as below:

```
set echo off;
set heading off;
set feedback off;
set linesize 32767;
set longchunksize 32767;
set long 2000000000;
set pagesize 0;
set heading off;
set wrap on;
set termout off;
set tab off;
set newpage 0;
```

I'm seeing new line between each returned records. But I want this new line to be removed.

Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't do it thru sqlplus commands hence I used linux shell commands